# Proposing questions for the C++-faq tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta-faq

I have question that I think would be a really good addition to the C++-faq tag, but how do I go about doing so?

Do I simply need to add the tag my self, or is there somewhere I can post a link for the question to be check for suitability.

What actually makes for a good question for the C++-faq tag? Obviously if a particular post has a very good answer to a question that is seen a lot, it should be part of the C++-faq. What about a question that is already covered by an 'faq' question, but I think this new one does a much better job of explaining it.

I have also seen some questions that whilst not directly asked a lot, do cover basic ground that those new to the language might come up against. As a prime example of this, I offer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057021/300797); it has some cross over with other questions, but this subject is not yet covered by the 'faq' tag.

I understand that the purpose of the faq was to help close duplicate questions with a good canonical answer, but there are some things that are hard for new people to ask, as they do not know the correct terminology. And so it might help improve the answers given if they can link to related questions/answers

Comment: Perhaps your best bet would be to discuss this in the C++ chat room with the very active C++ community. They no doubt have an opinion on the suitability of your question. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec

Comment: Came from there, I think something like could do with being up here any way

Comment: Ah, haha. Okay. Fair enough question I guess. Perhaps ask them for their input on this question here then. Some of them are active from time to time on Meta, but it would be good to know from those most active in the main tag anyway. Update: D'oh, I see you already told them. I will be on my way out now. ;)

Comment: Indeed. Work gets in the way of doing this sort of work properly though

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag

Also, discuss it in the lounge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's a community thing. Just post it and if people object then we'll take it down. There's no ceremony required. Except asking Uncle FAQ.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Uncle FAQ. :)

Comment: One of many: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=830508#830508